# Adobe HTTP Form submission - Windows Authentication

Tags: adobe, livecycle

I'm trying to get Windows Authentication to work in Adobe Form submissions. It works when I run things from my local host and my user id shows up but when I submit to a different machine, I keep getting the 401 - Not Authorized error. Is this not supported or am I missing some setting?

In case anyone is interested, the original problem is that we have HR policy documents as PDF files with a 'I Agree' button at the bottom and when user clicks the button, post it to server where I can track things. But without Windows Authentication, how can I identify the user?

Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a hidden field with the user's name / id? I do this with the fdf toolkit to make the forms interactive. Another option is to pass in the user's id as the value for the 'I Agree' button